# After Sign Out MSALwebView still shows previous user credentials in MSAL

Tags: ios, swift, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using azure ad b2c, reference document is : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal. when user sign out from account(Facebook is I am using in azure ad b2c) and again click on sign up button with another user then MSALwebView shows previously logged user detail(cache not cleared).

how to clear the MSALwebView cache ? is there any alternative way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Facebook accounts in AzureB2C. I only use internal accounts.
But to ensure that any account stored locally on the device is deleted after MSALPublicClientApplication.signout(...), I do the following:

```
// Delete every local account
let accounts = try application.allAccounts()

for account in accounts {
   try application.remove(account)
}
```

I'm not sure, if this is also working for third-party accounts like Facebook.